# How to most elegantly get named FileInfo from DirectoryInfo

Tags: c#, io

What is the most elegant way to get a named `FileInfo` from `DirectoryInfo`?

```
var myFileInfo = myDirectoryInfo.EnumerateFiles("filename.ext").FirstOrDefault();
```

or

```
var myFileInfo = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(myDirectoryInfo.FullName, "filename.ext"));
```

or anything else?

Comment: `EnumerateFiles` can be too slow (imagine, that you have `1_000_000` files in a folder). The second (direct) version looks better

Comment: @DmitryBychenko `EnumerateFiles()` used with `FirstOrDefault()` will only access the first item - it won't iterate over all the results.